# How to Use Enumeration within Linq Query to Update Multiple Rows in a Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have a View where I can see a few rows (expenses) and I have a checkbox inputs beside each row. There is a Boolean property called "Submitted" and a DateTime property called DateSubmitted in the model.

I have a method called SubmitExpenses() and I only want the rows that are 'checked' to be updated.

The columns that would be updated are DateSubmitted and Submitted.

Here is my model:

```
public class Expense
{
    public Expense() { }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Submitted")]
    public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Expense Date")]
    public DateTime? ExpenseDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Submitted?")]
    public bool Submitted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the SubmitExpenses() method:

```
public ActionResult SubmitExpenses(List<Expense> expenses, DateTime? expenseDate = null, DateTime? expenseDate2 = null, int? userId = 0)
{
    expenseDate = (DateTime)Session["FirstDate"];
    expenseDate2 = (DateTime)Session["SecondDate"];

    if (expenseDate == null || expenseDate2 == null)
    {
        expenseDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        expenseDate2 = DateTime.Today;
    }

    string currentUserId = User.Identity.Name;

    var query = from e in db.Expenses
                join user in db.UserProfiles on e.UserId equals user.UserId
                where user.UserName == currentUserId && (e.ExpenseDate >= expenseDate && e.ExpenseDate <= expenseDate2) && e.DateSubmitted == null
                orderby e.ExpenseDate descending
                select e;

    if (User.IsInRole("admin") && userId != 0)
    {

        query = from e in db.Expenses
                join user in db.UserProfiles on e.UserId equals user.UserId
                where user.UserId == userId && e.ExpenseDate >= expenseDate && e.ExpenseDate <= expenseDate2 && e.DateSubmitted == null
                orderby e.ExpenseDate descending
                select e;
    }
    else if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        query = from e in db.Expenses
                join user in db.UserProfiles on e.UserId equals user.UserId
                where e.ExpenseDate >= expenseDate && e.ExpenseDate <= expenseDate2 && e.DateSubmitted == null
                orderby e.ExpenseDate descending
                select e;
    }


    foreach (Expense exp in query)
    {
        exp.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Today;
    }

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return RedirectToAction("Submit");
    }

}
```

Here is the View:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateSubmitted)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpenseDate)
        </th>

        @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserProfile.UserName)
            </th>
        }
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Select All:</b>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="expense" value="Expense" id="selectAllCheckboxes" class="expenseCheck">
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="submitCheck">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Submitted)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateSubmitted)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseDate)
            </td>

            @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserProfile.UserName)
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }

</table>

 @Html.ActionLink("Submit Expenses", "SubmitExpenses")

 @section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">


    $("#selectAllCheckboxes").click(function () {
        $('.submitCheck input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $('.submitCheck input:checkbox').prop('disabled', false);


</script>

}
```

I know how to submit all expenses that are in the date range specified (or all expenses that are showing in the view), but I'm not sure how I would update each row for only the rows that are checked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as an aside, you can use query composition instead of repeating your query each time:

```
var query = from e in db.Expenses
            join user in db.UserProfiles on e.UserId equals user.UserId
            where e.ExpenseDate >= expenseDate && e.ExpenseDate <= expenseDate2 && e.DateSubmitted == null
            orderby e.ExpenseDate descending
            select new { e, user };

if (User.IsInRole("admin") && userId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.user.UserId == userId);
}
else if (!User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.user.UserName == currentUserId);
}
```

Now for the question: If I understand you correctly you want to filter out the Expenses from the database that were marked as `Submitted` in the view. These filtered expenses should be updated. A way to do that is by joining the database expenses with the ones from the view:

```
var joined = from dbExpense in query.Select(x => x.e).AsEnumerable()
             join localExpense in expenses on dbExpense.ExpenseId equals localExpense.ExpenseId
             where localExpense.Submitted
             select dbExpense;

foreach (Expense exp in joined)
{
    exp.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Today;
}
```

By using `AsEnumerable` on the database query, you can join it with a local sequence (`expenses`) as LINQ to objects.

Comment: Thank you for the style tips. I didn't know I could shorten my code like that! I was just wondering where the 'e' in 'x.e' comes from.

Comment: From `new { e, user }`.

Comment: The 'joined' variable is coming back as null. Is there anything I need to do in the view to get variable to be set?

Comment: `joined` is null? I can't imagine that, because the result of a LINQ query returning an enumerable is never null. Or is it empty?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I cannot view the value when I set a break point because it gives me the error: **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inner**

Comment: Isn't `expenses` null?

Comment: I think that's probably what's causing it, but shouldn't there be a list of 'expenses' being passed to the controller from the checked expenses in the view?

Comment: I guess so, yes, but I'm not too well versed in ASP.Net MVC. Just did some basic stuff with it a while ago.

Comment: No problem, I'll try to figure out how to get the list of expenses from the view to the controller, but you've pretty much answered my question about how to enumerate multiple items in a Linq query. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer last week. It wasn't easy, but I figured out how to pass a list, or array from the view back to the controller. For your reference, you can see how I did it from my SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220659/how-to-pass-a-list-of-items-from-view-to-controller-asp-net-mvc-4).