# How to Pass a List of Items from View to Controller (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to pass multiple **items** of type **List<item>** to my controller, however, when I submit my data, it show as null in my controller.

What I would like to happen is that I have a list of 'expenses' in the View, and beside each 'expense' or item is a checkbox from the **Submitted** Boolean property in my Model. When I check the items, I would like the list of checked items' properties **Submitted** and **DateSubmitted** to be updated in the database.

**@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Submitted)** in the View produces checkboxes.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Expenses.Models.Expense>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Submit Expenses";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
string formattedDate = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h2>Submit Expenses</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Start Date:</h4>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("expenseDate", formattedDate, htmlAttributes: new
           {
               @class = "form-control"
           })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>End Date:</h4>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("expenseDate2", formattedDate, htmlAttributes: new
           {
               @class = "form-control"
           })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            <h4>Username:</h4>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("UserId", String.Empty)
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Retrieve Expenses" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<br />
<br />


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Province)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReceiptName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GrossAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaxAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NetAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mileage)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TravelStatus)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LunchLearnStatus)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WithClientStatus)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateEntered)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateSubmitted)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpenseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageName)
        </th>
        @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserProfile.UserName)
            </th>
        }
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Select All:</b>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="expense" value="Expense" id="selectAllCheckboxes" class="expenseCheck">
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="submitCheck">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Submitted)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Province)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReceiptName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrossAmount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaxAmount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NetAmount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mileage)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TravelStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LunchLearnStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WithClientStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEntered)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateSubmitted)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.ImageName != null)
                {
                    <a href="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserProfile.FullName)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageName)" class="imageClick" target="_blank"><img src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserProfile.FullName)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageName)" alt="Image" style="width:80%" /></a>
                }
            </td>
            @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserProfile.UserName)
                </td>
            }
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ExpenseId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ExpenseId }) |
                @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ExpenseId })
                }

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

 @Html.ActionLink("Submit Expenses", "SubmitExpenses", "Expenses", null, new { @class = "submitLink", @style = "background-color: #d3dce0; border: 1px solid #787878; cursor: pointer; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 600; margin-right: 8px; padding: 7px; width: auto; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;"})

<div class="ExportSection" style="margin-top:30px;">
    @*<a href="javascript:void(0)">Export To CSV</a>*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Export To CSV", "ExportExpensesListToCSV")
</div>
}

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">


    $("#selectAllCheckboxes").click(function () {
        $('.submitCheck input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#expenseDate").datepicker();
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#expenseDate2").datepicker();
    });

</script>

}
```

and here is my Controller method:

```
public ActionResult SubmitExpenses(List<Expense> expenses, DateTime? expenseDate = null, DateTime? expenseDate2 = null, int? userId = 0)
    {
        expenseDate = (DateTime)Session["FirstDate"];
        expenseDate2 = (DateTime)Session["SecondDate"];

        if (expenseDate == null || expenseDate2 == null)
        {
            expenseDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            expenseDate2 = DateTime.Today;
        }

        string currentUserId = User.Identity.Name;

        var query = from e in db.Expenses
                    join user in db.UserProfiles on e.UserId equals user.UserId
                    where e.ExpenseDate >= expenseDate && e.ExpenseDate <= expenseDate2 && e.DateSubmitted == null
                    orderby e.ExpenseDate descending
                    select new { e, user };

        if (User.IsInRole("admin") && userId != 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.user.UserId == userId);
        }
        else if (!User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.user.UserName == currentUserId);
        }

        var expensesFromView = expenses;

        var joined = from dbExpense in query.Select(x => x.e).AsEnumerable()
                     join localExpense in expenses on dbExpense.ExpenseId equals localExpense.ExpenseId
                     where localExpense.Submitted
                     select dbExpense;

        foreach (Expense exp in joined)
        {
            exp.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Today;
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return RedirectToAction("Submit");
        }

    }
```

Here is my model:

```
[Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Receipt Name")]
    public string ReceiptName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Province { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gross Amount")]
    public decimal GrossAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "GST/HST Amount")]
    public decimal TaxAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Net Amount")]
    public decimal NetAmount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mileage (in Kilometers)")]
    public int Mileage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Travelling?")]
    public bool TravelStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lunch & Learn?")]
    public bool LunchLearnStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "With Clients?")]
    public bool WithClientStatus { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date Entered")]
    public DateTime? DateEntered{ get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Submitted")]
    public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Expense Date")]
    public DateTime? ExpenseDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Submitted?")]
    public bool Submitted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```

My variable `expensesFromView` is showing as null and as a result, I get an error on my `joined` query that says:

> **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inner**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't really find a way to pass a list of items directly from View to Controller, so I decided to use AJAX.

I changed the parameters of my Controller from type **List<>** to **int[ ]** to take an array of item IDs:

```
public ActionResult SubmitExpenses(int[] expenseIDs, DateTime? expenseDate = null, DateTime? expenseDate2 = null, int? userId = 0)
    {
        expenseDate = (DateTime)Session["FirstDate"];
        expenseDate2 = (DateTime)Session["SecondDate"];

        if (expenseDate == null || expenseDate2 == null)
        {
            expenseDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            expenseDate2 = DateTime.Today;
        }

        string currentUserId = User.Identity.Name;

        var query = from e in db.Expenses
                    join user in db.UserProfiles on e.UserId equals user.UserId
                    where e.ExpenseDate >= expenseDate && e.ExpenseDate <= expenseDate2 && e.DateSubmitted == null
                    orderby e.ExpenseDate descending
                    select new { e, user };

        if (User.IsInRole("admin") && userId != 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.user.UserId == userId);
        }
        else if (!User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.user.UserName == currentUserId);
        }

        //var localExpenseIDs = expenseIDs;

        var joined = from dbExpense in query.Select(x => x.e).AsEnumerable()
                     join localExpense in expenseIDs on dbExpense.ExpenseId equals localExpense
                     where localExpense == dbExpense.ExpenseId
                     select dbExpense;

        foreach (Expense exp in joined)
        {
            exp.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Today;
            exp.IsSubmitted = true;
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return RedirectToAction("Submit");
        }

    }
```

In my view, I assigned the ID of each item to the id of it's own HTML checkbox :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="checkbox-td">
                @Html.CheckBox("isSubmitted", new
           {
               @id = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseId),
               @class = "submitBox"
           })
            </td>
        </tr>
     }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Submit Expenses", "", "", null, new { @id = "submitExpensesLink" })
</div>
```

I wrote some jQuery, so that each checkbox that is checked, will add the id of the input element to an array and the array of integers would be *POSTed* to the **SubmitExpenses** action:

```
var checkedArray = [];

    $(':checkbox[name=isSubmitted]').on('change', function () {

        checkedArray = $(':checkbox[name=isSubmitted]:checked').map(function () {
                return this.id;
         })
        .get();


        //alert(checkedArray);
    });

    $('#submitExpensesLink').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            url: "@Url.Action("SubmitExpenses", "Expenses")",
            data: { expenseIDs: checkedArray },
        success: function () {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (debug) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this -

1 .

> You might need this extension which is really good and extensible- 
>   [MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList) -- SEEMS this site has been shut down :) refer the option 2

2 .

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{

     <tr>
      <td class="submitCheck">
       <input type="checkbox" value="@Model[i].Id" name="Expense[@i].Id">
       <input type="hidden" value="0" name="Expense[@i].Id">          
      </td>
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
      </td>
     </tr>
}
```

btw: if you use the second way : in your controller, filter for the zero value of  for the expense object's Id; coz if it is not selected, zero is sent to the controller (as the element's ID) grace to the "hidden" field you can see in the above code.

Comment: Thanks man. The link you gave me seems to be what I need. I'll try this out and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `FormMethod.Post` into @using `(Html.BeginForm()) {}`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("nameAction", "nameController", FormMethod.Post))
{
   //Your  code
}
```

2) You should to add name for inputs like this :

```
<input type="text" name="someName"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this and the data still isn't being passed properly.